# is Materialize css not updated anymore?

Tags: materialize

Been using Materialize css for so long now, and i see that it looks the same, no new components, with what i can see. Unlike how boostrap has really evolve over time. Materialize still looks Nice but, just wanna ask how well is the Framework going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [original repo](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize) is not actively maintained. But you'll find active commits on this [fork](https://github.com/materializecss/materialize), which is maintained by the same contributors on the original one.